# What is the second argument to the bind() socket function?

Tags: c, sockets

I'm new to C programming and currently studying Unix socket programming.

My question is what is the 2nd argument of bind function actually?

```
int main(){
    int mysocket;
    int portno = 5004;

    mysocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
    struct sockaddr_in *p = &serv_addr;

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);


    bind(mysocket, p, sizeof(serv_addr));
}
```

I try to pass `p`, `*p`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I am not sure about the type `Int` and function `Bind` but assuming `int` and  `bind`, `p` should be `const struct sockaddr *` type.

Comment: In general you google for such things - and you really need to learn how to search & read API documentation if you are to do programming. [This](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bind.2.html) might help, but other than that this kind of question is off topic for SO.

Comment: By "what is [it] actually?" do you mean what is its *type*? What is its *significance*?  What is its gender identity?

Comment: man 3 bind.  Tells you it should be a `const struct sockaddr *`.  `p` is a `sockaddr_in *` (which you point to the address of a `sock_addr`).  That might be a problem.

Comment: Please create your code on a system that does _not_ capitalize the first word on each line.  C is a case-sensitive language, so having all those leading capitals is confusing.  They could be what you really have, but they probably aren't.  Your references to `Serv_addr` after defining `serv_addr` is an example of the problem.

Comment: Sorry. There is alot mistake in the code. Now its fix. What should I do to the 2nd argument of that function? It still doesn't working.

Comment: Hey, wait a minute is it struct sockaddr is different from struct sockaddr_in?

Comment: Yes they are different.  Also you need to clear the struct before using it.

Comment: Thanks and what do you mean by clearing the struct before using it and how?

Answer (score 2):

The 2nd parameter of `bind()` is a pointer to a struct that describes the local interface to which the socket is to be bound (the 3rd parameter is the byte size of that struct).

`bind()` takes a `sockaddr*` pointer as input, but it actually accepts any `sockaddr_...` struct that matches the address family of the socket (`sockaddr_in` for `AF_INET`, `sockaddr_in6` for `AF_INET6`, `sockaddr_un` for `AF_UNIX`, etc).

Once upon a time, only `sockaddr` existed (for `AF_INET`), and BSD socket APIs (particularly `bind()`, `accept()`, `connect()`, and `get(sock|peer)name()`) were designed around `sockaddr`.  Later on, when new address families were introduced, `sockaddr_in` was created as a direct replacement for what `sockaddr` previously represented (an IPv4 address).  But the socket function interfaces were already set in stone and couldn't be changed.  That is why `sockaddr*` type-casts are needed when calling such functions.  All `sockaddr_...` structs (including `sockaddr` itself) begin with a 16-bit `family` identifier, so using such type-casts (in coordination with the associated byte-size parameter) are safe.

Now, in your example, `p` is being passed in the 2nd parameter, and `p` is declared as `Struct sockaddr_in *p = &serv_addr;`, so you are actually passing in the memory address of `serv_addr` (this code would only compile if the parameter were declared as `void*`, otherwise you would need a `sockaddr*` typecast - this is platform-dependent!).  `serv_addr` is populated with an IPv4 address (`INADDR_ANY`, aka `0.0.0.0`) and a port number (`portno`, in network byte order).  The 3rd parameter is set to `sizeof(serv_addr)`.

So, between that size value and `serv_addr.sin_family` being set to `AF_INET`, `bind()` knows that you are passing in a `sockaddr_in` struct, and will validate and use it accordingly.

Comment: Gee thanks. So, I see that the only way to succeed that bind function is by: sockaddr* typecast. TYPECASTing a pointer of a type to a pointer of another type. In my case is: typecasting pointer p which uses type sockaddr_in to pointer that uses type sockaddr.  Like following: bind(mysocket, (struct sockaddr*) p, sizeof(serv_addr)).

Comment: @assdfas yes, or pass `serv_addr` directly: `bind(mysocket, (struct sockaddr*) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));`

Comment: Yea it works. Both of them: my statement and yours. Now I succeded.What is a typecasting pointer variable of a type to another type of data anyway? I see the difference between structure sockaddr and sockaddr_in. Sockaddr only holds 2 member, and sockaddr_in holds 3 member. So I need to typecast it from 3 member structures to 2 member structures?

Comment: @assdfas you are not typecasting the struct itself. You are typecasting just a pointer from one type to another. The data being pointed to stays the same, the data is simply interpreted differently based on what type of pointer is pointing at it.

Comment: Thanks, I kind a get it. But stil winding. I need to dive more again about typecasting. Typecasting a pointer variable of a type to another only change the width it can get? Am I right? For instance: int a = 10; float *p = (float *)&a; printf("%i,%i",sizeof(p),sizeof(&a));

Comment: @assdfas a typecast *reinterprets* the bytes in a different way. Typecasting an `int*` to a `float*` doesn't magically make the data be a `float`. And FYI, all pointers are the same size regardless of type.

Answer (score 0):

Gee thanks. So historically, at first there is only struct sockaddr structure and later time there are many structures invented such as: struc sockaddr_in, sockaddr_un structures. But bind function already designed with a pointer variable to the first or the beginning structure sockaddr (the first structure in history) and now I used a sockaddr_in.
 I see that the only way to succeed that bind function is by: sockaddr* typecast: TYPECASTing a pointer of a type to a pointer of another type. In my case is: typecasting pointer p which uses type sockaddr_in to pointer that uses type sockaddr.  Like following: bind(mysocket, (struct sockaddr*) p, sizeof(serv_addr)) and it works.